# For which values of $x \in R$ does the series $\{x^\mathrm{k_n}\}^\infty_\mathrm{n=1}$ converge.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Say that I have the sequence $\{a_n\}^\infty_\mathrm{n=1}$ that is a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers. For which

values of $x \in R$ does the series $\{x^\mathrm{a_n}\}^\infty_\mathrm{n=1}$ converge.

I tried to work through comparisons for this and know that series $(x^n)$ converges in $(-1,1)$ and diverges elsewhere. Not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Use the fact that $k_n\ge n$ and hence $|x^{k_n}|<|x|^n$ if $|x|<1$. The divergence domain is also reachable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the series
$$ \sum x^n$$
converges exactlyif $|x|<1$, and thus it also converges absolutely. This means that
$\sum x^{a_n}$ as a subseries has to converge as well.

On the other hand if $|x|\geq 1$ then $|x^{a_n}|$ does not go to $0$. Thus the series cannot converge.